# How do i make it so i have 4 rows and the result class is on the top using flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a very simple calculator, but its just not coming out the way i want it to. any ideas? It should be 4 rows a with the 0 on top to display result later.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.square {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <h1>0</h1>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="square row1">
    <h2>0</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row1" "><h2>1</h2></div>
<div class="square row1 "">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row1" "><h2>3</h2></div>
<div class="square row1 "">
    <h2>4</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="square row2" "><h2>5</h2></div>
<div class="square row2 "">
    <h2>6</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row2" "><h2>7</h2></div>
<div class="square row2 "">
    <h2>8</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row2" "><h2>9</h2></div>

<div class="square row3 "">
    <h2>C</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row3" "><h2>.</h2></div>
<div class="square row3 "">
    <h2>+/-</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row3" "><h2>*</h2></div>
<div class="square row3 "">
    <h2>\</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="square row4" "><h2>-</h2></div>
<div class="square row4 "">
    <h2>+</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row4" "><h2>=</h2></div>  
</div>
```

this is just extra words bc it required more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some of your code is invalid, that's going to be part of the issue. In many of your class definitions you have the incorrect number of quotation marks. I've taken the liberty of fixing those issues but also updating the semantics of your markup to better align with its use case. This means updating number divs to be `button`s and swapping the `h1` and `h2`s on the page for `span`s.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.square {
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.result {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="result">
    <span>0</span>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <button class="square">
      <span>0</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>1</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>2</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>3</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>4</span>
    </button>

    <button class="square">
      <span>5</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>6</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>7</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>8</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>9</span>
    </button>

    <button class="square">
      <span>C</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>.</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>+/-</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>*</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>\</span>
    </button>

    <button class="square">
      <span>-</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>+</span>
    </button>
    <button class="square">
      <span>=</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I removed your flexbox fix and swapped it for CSS Grid instead. This allows us to define a grid once and let the items flow into it.

By defining the CSS Grid on the parent `#container` we can set 5 columns (4 rows) as you've requested. This will align each child into a column. An `fr` is a fractional unit, since there are 5, it will divide the available space evenly into 5 columns.

I also added the `.wrap` div around everything to allow us to position your `.result` output. By adding `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` to the `.wrap` div we can align both the `.result` and `#container` divs to be stacked. Then by setting `align-self: end;` on the `.result` div we can bump the output to the right as it would display on most calculators.

Here's all that code in a codepen: https://codepen.io/goodwinc/pen/ZEzBWoJ

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest change is to make the width of `.square` be 20% not 7%. This will let 5 elements fit onto one row, and with the `flex-wrap: wrap` on the `#container`, this will let everything work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: block !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#container {
    border: none;
}
.square {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the width as `7%` for the .square so you got lots of buttons on the same row.
Hence you need to give the width as `25%` in order to get 4 buttons.
Same way you have given `display:flex` for the `body` so to align your `0` above add `flex-direction:column` to the body

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.square {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <h1>0</h1>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="square row1">
    <h2>0</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row1">
    <h2>1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row1">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row1">
    <h2>3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row1">
    <h2>4</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="square row2">
    <h2>5</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row2">
    <h2>6</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row2">
    <h2>7</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row2">
    <h2>8</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row2">
    <h2>9</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="square row3">
    <h2>C</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row3">
    <h2>.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row3">
    <h2>+/-</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row3">
    <h2>*</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row3">
    <h2>\</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="square row4">
    <h2>-</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row4">
    <h2>+</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="square row4" "><h2>=</h2></div>  
</div>
```